# Convert Tagify javascript array to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm trying to convert this [Tagify script](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify) from an *array* to a *string*. The problem is all the output from Tagify contains value and comma's and I've so far been unable to convert these array's to a nice string. How would I go about this?

I'm using the script to create tags that are then used in a search (GET). I get this in the URL `?query=[{"value"%3A"bee"}]` instead of `?query=bee`

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[name=query]'),
  // init Tagify script on the above inputs
  tagify = new Tagify(input, {
    // after 2 characters typed, all matching values from this list will be suggested in a dropdown
    whitelist: ["Door", "Cat", "Mouse", "Chicken", "Duck"]
  })
```

Comment: Please post the code that updates the page's `location` with the `tagify.value`. That is the crucial point where things needed to be done.

Comment: At which point in the program's flow do you need the *Array* be converted to a *String*?

Answer (score 6):

To change the format, assuming your tags have no commas you can use the `originalInputValueFormat` [*setting*](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify#settings):

```
var tagify = new Tagify(input, {
// after 2 characters typed, all matching values from this list will be suggested in a dropdown
  whitelist: ["Door", "Cat", "Mouse", "Chicken", "Duck"],
  originalInputValueFormat: valuesArr => valuesArr.map(item => item.value).join(', ')
})
```

Output:
"Cat, Mouse"